# How to set character limit on a link length

Tags: html, character, limit

I have a RSS FEED box where shows a number of links from the Feed.
The size of box is specified for 10 links and each link on 1 line.
However sometimes when the length of the title is long the link will be in two or more lines and it will deform the box.
How can I set limit characters to the length of title (link)?
Like if a link is too long at the end of the link add three dots:
Example: How do I set limit on character...

This is the feed that I'm using:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://rss.artaweb.biz//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Farabic%2Findex.xml&num=10&targ=y&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first put an id or class to your div in which you are putting or showing your rss feed like

```
<div id="some-id">
   // your rss feed script
</div>
```

then you can use this jquery script to limit the text to show up to specific characters

```
$("div#some-id").text(function(index, text) {
   return text.substr(0, characters you want);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help.
So this is what I used however it didn't work. as if nothing happened:
`<div id="limit">
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://rss.artaweb.biz//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Farabic%2Findex.xml&num=10&targ=y&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>`
`<script>
$("div#limit").text(function(index, text) {
   return text.substr(0, 45);
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You use CSS to:

1. Disallow for line breaks
2. Add ellipsis to overflowing text

So, for example, if you wrap the script in a `div` with id links:

```
#links li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demonstrated in fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/V9PXL/. Try reszing the window to see what happens.

Comment: This is cool but the Ellipsis didn't work. The links comes long in a line and it make the block very big